# Java print output into a csv file

Tags: java, csv, printing, output

So I have this code:

```
          public class UtilsGrafos {
                 public static void main (String[]args) {

           double [] c={1.0,2.1,3.2};
           Grafo M= new Grafo(4);
           M.add_edge(2, 3,c);


        System.out.println(M.parametrosaresta(2,3)[1]);


    }
}
```

and I want to print this output into a csv file. I know the general code of opening the file and having the hardwriting there, but how do I 'ask' it to get this Output?

Answer (score 0):

```
String csv = "C:\\output2.csv";
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
data.add(new String[] {"India", "New Delhi"});
data.add(new String[] {"United States", "Washington D.C"});
data.add(new String[] {"Germany", "Berlin"});

writer.writeAll(data);

writer.close();
```

Read this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/

Comment: Yes, but here on 
    data.add(new String[] {"India", "New Delhi"});

how can I, instead of writing India and New Deli, can get the output from my 

    System.out.println(M.parametrosaresta(2,3)[1]);

?

Answer (score 0):

You do not use System.out *ever* (except for debugging or while in development). Commit that to mind.

If you want a method to output to *somehere* you add a method parameter that tells it where to write to (e.g. an OutputStream or some kind of StreamWriter). You then pass the method the output target you want it to write to. Simple and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library.